# Closed questions allow empty titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, title

Apparently when a question is closed, the post is allowed to be edited and saved with an empty title, which leaves the post title as simply `[closed]`.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365764/

Oops, that's supposed to be a link. I guess having no title breaks the automatic text conversion of SO posts from url to title, try this instead:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365764/
```

Here's the revision link in case the post is rolled back, hopefully it's clear what happened:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9365764/2

I know this isn't a huge deal seeing as the question is closed, but I'm not sure what would happen if the post was reopened. It might end up with a completely empty title that's unclickable from the main page.

Either way, I'm reporting this because I believe it is unintentional behavior.

Comment: Must resist... urge to roll back.... Must not... destroy only example... of bug....

Comment: @PopularDemand [What a jerk](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9365764/3).

Comment: Good catch! I think it's actually fairly important, as closed questions are perhaps more likely to be attempted to be edited to an empty title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great find - this was due to our stripping of punctuation from titles *after* doing validation.

A fix will be deployed in the next build, > `rev 2012.2.24.1225`.